# Flutter DateTime serializer with null safety

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, built-value

I'm using built_value in flutter, both libraries are null safe

```
built_value_generator: ^8.0.4
built_value: ^8.0.4
```

In my model I have a few DateTime objects they are all nullable. To serialize these I'm using a custom serializer that returns null if the string is null or empty. but it throws an exception

```
  Deserializing '[data, [{_id: 609e6ea910fd591efebd61a3, booking_id: 
  609e6ea99fe023fde50aa375,...' to 'BookingResponse' failed due to: Deserializing '[{_id: 
  609e6ea910fd591efebd61a3, booking_id: 609e6ea99fe023fde50aa375, client...' to 
  'BuiltList<Booking>' failed due to: Deserializing '[_id, 609e6ea910fd591efebd61a3, 
  booking_id, 609e6ea99fe023fde50aa375, client,...' to 'Booking' failed due to: type 'Null' 
  is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast
```

The exception happens when I deserialize an empty string to a DateTime declared in my model like this :

```
 DateTime? get booking_date;
```

using the serializer below (which will return null)

```
class DateTimeSerializer implements PrimitiveSerializer<DateTime?> {
  @override
  DateTime? deserialize(Serializers serializers, Object? serialized, {FullType specifiedType = FullType.unspecified}) {
   logger('DateTime.deserialize: $serialized');
    if (serialized != null && serialized is String && serialized.isNotEmpty) {
      logger('DateTime.deserialize parse: $serialized');
      return DateTime.parse(serialized).toLocal();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Object serialize(Serializers serializers, DateTime? object, {FullType specifiedType = FullType.unspecified}) {
   logger('DateTime.serialize: $object');
    if (object != null) {
      return object.toUtc().toIso8601String();
    } else {
      return Object();
    }
  }

  @override
  Iterable<Type> get types => [DateTime];

  @override
  String get wireName => 'DateTime';
}
```

in my generated model I can see this :

```
     case 'booking_date':
      result.booking_date = serializers.deserialize(value,
          specifiedType: const FullType(DateTime)) as DateTime;
      break;
```

which suggests this can't be null, but then it also has this

```
DateTime? _booking_date;
DateTime? get booking_date => _$this._booking_date;
set booking_date(DateTime? booking_date) =>
  _$this._booking_date = booking_date;
```

which makes me think it can be, any idea why this would throw an exception?

Comment: Does it change anything to play with « specifiedType: const FullType(DateTime)) as DateTime » ? For instance replacing it with « specifiedType: const FullType(DateTime)) as DateTime? »

Comment: thats the generated code though and tbh i dont think that changes anything specified full type is just what it should be parsed as, in the implementation it checks if its null before trying to parse it as that type

Comment: i can make it not crash by returning DateTime.now() from the else clause in the deserialize method

Comment: This is definitely bug in built_value_generator. So I suggest creating an issue in its GitHub. I tried your example and noticed that it happens only in  case of empty string though. If field is missing or field is explicitly null, input is deserialized fine. If you have control over API you are consuming I suggest to fix it on API side - having empty strings to represent nulls is bad idea.

Comment: yeah i have told them this and I am hoping that they make this change however deadlines etc thanks though appreciate the sanity check,

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky if you add this as an answer and raise the bug ill award you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this as a bug in built_value_generator: https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/1035

Generated code has incorrect cast to DateTime, while it should have a cast to DateTime?.

When changing cast to **DateTime?** in generated code - deserialization works fine.